Stable/metastable nuclei with excited nucleon states
I was reading about nucleon excited states such as the delta, and saw a passing comment that some nuclei may have a delta or N particle in place of an ordinary nucleon, and that said nuclei were “stable”. (Confession: I read it in wiki. Don’t judge me!)
I did a little googling but only found some theoretical work relating to extreme conditions such as neutron stars. Does anyone know if such nuclei actually exist in the real world and, if so, can give me some pointers to reading material?
For emphasis, I’m not talking about regular nucleons in higher shells or nuclear isomers. I’m asking about something where one or more individual nucleons are replaced by resonances.
`

you should at least link to the wiki page so that we might look at the context

You are excluding hypernuclei, right?

This paper argues about misinterpretations to phantom Δ bound states.

The wiki article was https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nucleon#Nucleon_resonances. See comment sbout Li 6 under the table. Yes, I’m excluding hypernuclei.

Here is a summary, but it is a can or worms... No, you are not judged, perhaps they are...

Thanks for that summary.
